# A bash commands log

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, debian, google-compute-engine

I'm using Google Compute Engine Debian 11 Wordpress. Is there a way to log what bash commands are executed for VM and by who? I couldn't find the information in Logging and Monitoring.

Comment: IIRC the SSH server can log commands. Then you need to configure Cloud Logging to include that log file. Start the SSH server log file `auth.log`. You might need to modify `sshd_config` to enable logging.

Comment: Configure Cloud Logging to include `auth.log`: https://serverfault.com/a/955094/437769